# $\Bbb R[x]/(x^2-1)\cong \Bbb R[x]/(x-1)\times \Bbb R[x]/(x+1)\cong \Bbb R^2\,$ via Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm currently following my 2nd algebra course at uni where we are discussing rings.

The assignment goes like this
$$\text{Show that} \ \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1) \ \text{is isomorphic to} \ \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$$

$\mathbb{R}[x]$ is the polynomial ring and $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1)$ is then a quotient ring. A hint to solve it is to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

I am stumped. The hint implies to me that $(x^2-1)$ must be the kernel of some ring homomorphism. It also to me implies that there is an ideal in $\mathbb{R}[x]$, let's call it K, so that $\mathbb{R}[x]/K=\mathbb{R}$ and I can't make either of those things to make sense. Is it also right to assume that $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1)=\{f(x)+x^2-1\vert f(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]\}=\mathbb{R}[x]$, since all equivalence classes will contain just one element, since for two elements to be in the same equivalence class, the polynomials must be the same? Like if,

$$q(x)+x^2-1=r(x)+x^2-1\Leftrightarrow q(x)=r(x)$$
for $q(x),r(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider the map $\phi:\mathbb R[x] \to \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi(f)=(f(1),f(-1))$. Prove that $f$ is a surjective ring homomorphism and compute its kernel.

Comment: Okay this put what Bernard said into a more understandable context for a pleb like me. It's surjective because we have the constant polynomials and the kernel is all polynomials that can be factored into $(x^2-1)f(x)$ for some polynomial in $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Comment: But I have questions to the notation in the assignment then..

Comment: Am I right about my description of $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1)$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

As you know, $X^2-1=(X-1)(X+1)$ and the factors are coprime, hence by the *Chinese remainder theorem*,
$$\mathbf R[X]/(X^2-1)\simeq \mathbf R[X]/(X-1)\times\mathbf R[X]/(X+1).$$

Comment: But how are (x-1) and (x+1) comaximal ideals? Even just ideals.

Comment: They're distinct maximal ideals, that's all.

Comment: Am I to assume that (x-1) is actually the ring and ideal $\mathbb{R}[x](x-1)$?

Comment: No. Each quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbf R$, by the maps $P(X)\mapsto P(1)$ and $P(-1)$ respectively

Comment: I think there are some general things about polynomial rings that has blown by me. I will take a look at this again later.

Comment: You just have to know that $P(X)\bmod (X-\alpha)$  has $P(\alpha)$ as a representative, since it is the remainder of the Euclidean division by $X-\alpha$.